# Node JS Nested Array Transformation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to transform `following array` but it's only transforming single level. multiple remain same want to remove entity for each level of object.

I have used the map to modify object not sure if there are others method for the multi level

Here is the array

```
const source = [
  {
    "block_id": 1,
    "entity": 100,
    "block_name": "test 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "block_id": 2,
        "entity": 101,
        "block_name": "test 2",
        "children": [
          {
            "block_id": 3,
             "entity": 105,
            "block_name": "test 2",
          }

        ]
      }
      
    ],
  }
]
```

Tried following code to transform

```
function trans(item) {
  const items = Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item];
    return items.map( t => {
        return { block_id: t.block_id, block_name: t.block_name, children: t.children };
    });
}
```

I am getting following

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "block_id": 1,
    "block_name": "test 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "block_id": 2,
        "entity": 101,
        "block_name": "test 2",
        "children": [
          {
            "block_id": 3,
            "entity": 105,
            "block_name": "test 2",
          }

        ]
      }
      
    ],
  }
]
```

**Expected**

```
[
  {
    "block_id": 1,
    "block_name": "test 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "block_id": 2,
        "block_name": "test 2",
        "children": [
          {
            "block_id": 3,
            "block_name": "test 2",
          }

        ]
      }
      
    ],
  }
]
```

Please help

Comment: You can do it well using recurison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanted result can be implemented easily with `recursion`:

```js
const source = [ { "block_id": 1, "entity": 100, "block_name": "test 1", "children": [ { "block_id": 2, "entity": 101, "block_name": "test 2", "children": [ { "block_id": 3, "entity": 105, "block_name": "test 2", } ] } ], }];

const transform=arr=>arr.map(({entity,...rest})=> rest.children ? ({...rest, children: transform(rest.children)}) : rest);

console.log(transform(source));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind to change your origin Array ,you can try this codes:

```js
function trans(item, element) {
    const items = Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item];
    items.forEach(t => {
        if (typeof t === 'object') {
            if (element in t) {
                delete t[element]
            }
            for (const argument in t) {
                const item = t[argument]
                if (typeof item === 'object') {
                    trans(item,element)
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and the result is:

```js
const source = [
    {
        "block_id": 1,
        "entity": 100,
        "block_name": "test 1",
        "children": [
            {
                "block_id": 2,
                "entity": 101,
                "block_name": "test 2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "block_id": 3,
                        "entity": 105,
                        "block_name": "test 2",
                    }

                ]
            }

        ],
    }
]

function trans(item, element) {
    const items = Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item];
    items.forEach(t => {
        if (typeof t === 'object') {
            if (element in t) {
                delete t[element]
            }
            for (const argument in t) {
                const item = t[argument]
                if (typeof item === 'object') {
                    trans(item, element)
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

trans(source, 'entity')

console.log(JSON.stringify(source, null, 2));
```